# Included fields in Response in ModelSerializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

**This is probably a very simple question, but I cant seem to solve it.**

I have a ModelSerializer like so:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # http -v POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/user-list/ email="f@b.de" password="123"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserModel.objects.create(
            email=validated_data['email']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        return user


    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = (
            'email',
            'password',
            'is_active',
            'company',
            'name',
        )
        read_only_fields = ('is_active',)
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
        }
```

The corresponding view looks like this:

```
class UserDetail(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            user = request.user
            serializer = UserMailSerializer(user)
            print(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

When I sent a GET request the serializer.data will only return the 'email' address (I am using a custom User Model with the email as primary identification).

I want to return all the fields that are not specified as write_only. How Do I achieve this?

Comment: Check your views, Serializer is different than what you have specified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **`UserMailSerializer`** serializer class in your views, which may be the wrong one. Use **`UserSerializer`** serializer instead

```
class UserDetail(APIView):

    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request):
        try:
            user = request.user

            serializer = UserSerializer(user) # change is here <<<<<

            print(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: Wow - this is really embarrassing for me -.-